# VBA Using a mapping table to copy values from one sheet to another based on headers

Tags: vba, dictionary, header, copy, mapping

I have a workbook with Sheet1, Sheet2, Mapping. I want to copy values from Sheet 2 to Sheet 1 based on both row/column headers in both sheets (this is working fine). The column headers could not be the same, so I created a mapping table in "Mapping" Sheet to match those headers but I don't know how to include it.  So any advice is appreciated :)
[Sheet2-source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGVaZ.png), [Sheet1-destination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKvf9.png), [mapping table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwH4q.png), [the result that I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sG8ui.png)

```
Sub WB_CopyData()
    Dim iRowHeader As Integer, iColHeader As Integer
    Dim rngSrc As Range, rngDest As Range, celSrc As Range, celDest As Range
    Dim shtSrc As Worksheet, shtDest As Worksheet, shtHelper As Worksheet
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    
    Set wb1 = Workbooks("Report2.xlsx")
    Set wb2 = Workbooks("Report1.xlsx")
    Set wb3 = Workbooks("Control.xlsm")
    
    Set shtSrc = wb1.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set shtDest = wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set shtHelper = wb3.Worksheets("Mapping")
    
    iRowHeaderSrc = 2
    iColHeaderSrc = 2
    
    iRowHeaderDest = 2
    iColHeaderDest = 1
    
    Set rngSrc = shtSrc.Range("$C$3:$G$6")
    'Here I used a named range. Sheet2 is the name of the range because I want to copy values from the sheet "Sheet2"
    Set rngDest = shtDest.Range("Sheet2")
    
    For Each celDest In rngDest
        For Each celSrc In rngSrc
                If shtSrc.Cells(celSrc.Row, iColHeaderSrc).Value = shtDest.Cells(celDest.Row, iColHeaderDest).Value And _
                   shtSrc.Cells(iRowHeaderSrc, celSrc.Column).Value = shtDest.Cells(iRowHeaderDest, celDest.Column).Value Then
                   celDest.Value = celSrc.Value
                End If
            Next celSrc
        Next celDest
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually you can use `sumfifs` to perform calculation without the need of VBA, do you really need to use VBA?

Comment: Yea because I have multiple workbooks and I need to automate them :(

Comment: I see, it will be quite tedious to solve since involve different wb with different header. Hope someone may help you :)